# Common practice to consume API for information intense application and database design Ruby on Rails

Tags: database, api, database-design

Let's say I am developing meta-search app for hotel bookings using API of Expedia, Booking etc on Ruby on Rails.

What is the best way to consume API if I want to render hotels list in accordance with "arrival date", "departure date" and "longitude" "latitude" in radius 20 miles.

I have every coordinate needed for such search (around 10 thousand coords).

So if I make such search it returns more than 100 hotels within 20 miles for each coordinate, so there are tens of thousands unique hotels.

Should I pre-seed my database with all hotels for each coordinate and consume only number of rooms available and other dynamic variables, or it will be better to render list dynamically through Javascript?

Also that is the best database for this task? i am interested in Expedia affiliate program in particular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested, I found the answer to my question.

Take a look at the Expedia API documentation closer http://developer.ean.com/docs/read/hotels, especially the databases section (need to sign in). I found that there may be several approaches to this problem depending on the application. I've stopped on the option of importing the whole property database, which is fully accessible on the Expedia site and consume only dynamic parameters like Room Availability, prices, etc. However this will require frequent updates to the database.